# Ajax upload call upload button from another element click

Tags: jquery, ajax, image-uploading

i am using Ajax Upload to upload maximum 6 images one by one.
I got prepared layout with div for each image and i would like that the upload action to be triggered when i click on the divs. I tried this but don't work

```
$('#uplimage1').click(function() {
    $('#upload').click();
});
```

this is my ajax call

```
(function(){    
    var btnUpload=$('#upload');
    var status=$('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
```

I have multiple functions with the images like rotate, change the order so every div has an uniq id #uplimage1 to #uplimage6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "fire off" a click event that resides on another element, you need to use [**`trigger()`**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('#uplimage1').click(function() {
    $('#upload').trigger("click");
});
```

This will fire off the `click()` event of the `#upload` element.